# WSDL.exe - How do I generate cs file

Tags: proxy, wsdl, wsdl.exe

I have local wsdl-file, and related xsd-files and I want to generate a cs-file.

Now i succeded in generate cs-file with the following command:

All is fine!!

Answer (score 0):

Start "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019" and run th following command:
wsdl.exe C:\file.wsdl C:\file1.xsd C:\file2.xsd c:\file3.xsd c:\file4.xsd